# iOS-Availability of Google Play Game Services Turn-based Multiplayer

Tags: android, ios, google-play-games

The Google Play Game Services Turn-based Multiplayer component is currently only available for Android. Are there any stated plans to make it available on iOS-clients?

If not, are there any alternative turn-based libraries that work across iOS/Android (e.g. using Facebook friends as game-participants)?

Comment: Hi Stan, please see https://developers.google.com/games/services/ Most of the Google Play Game Services components are available for iOS. The turn-based multiplayer is marked as "new" and "Android/web only" and I'm wondering whether iOS compatibility will follow or isn't on the roadmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Games services now offers turn-based multiplayer support for iOS. Here's the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/turnbasedMultiplayer

Comment: Thanks, I saw the announcement but forgot to update/answer my question :)!